# How to persist subscription and user data to my database during ios app onboarding?

Tags: ios, postgresql, in-app-purchase

I recently saw some onboarding flows for some popular ios applications and I got very confused.

They have an onboarding flow where they ask users onboarding questions such as: 1.name 2.height 3. weight 4. reason for joining and etc.

Then before the authentication, they present a paywall to subscribe, so you can become a paying customer without even having an account?

I currently have postgres database with these relevant tables - `users` and `subscribers`.

For most onboarding questions I have columns - `id`, `reason_to_join`,`height`, `weight`... where as for subscriptions i have `user_id` and status columns in `subscribers` table.

It seems that ios subscriptions are associated with particular device rather than email address, so how does this even work (persisting onboarding and subscription status data) with my current setup?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask user if they prefer to create new account or to enter existing.
2. In case user selects registration, request a `user_id` from back-end for so called "guest session" before presenting onboarding flow. If your `user_id` is an auto increment integer, also provide some `confirmation_token` to prevent abusing user ids.
3. Associate your onboarding details and purchase data with the `user_id` as you're doing it usually.
4. For the case, when user deletes the app after purchasing, but before providing login details, you should always provide a "Restore purchases" button on your payment page. Your back-end should associate the subscription to the newer `user_id`.
5. After passing onboarding, submit your `user_id` for guest session, `confirmation_token` obtained at step 2, and login details (email/password, or 3rd party auth token).